# Stuck on a log equation

Tags: logarithms

I am having trouble figuring out how I can solve this log:

$$6 \log(x^2+1)-x=0$$

The steps i've thought to take so far are as follows:

step 1: subtract the right most x to the other side of the equation:

$$6 \log(x^2+1) = x$$

step 2: divide by 6:

$$\log(x^2+1)=\frac{x}{6}$$

step 3: make both sides an exponent of 10 to get rid of the log:

$$x^2+1 = 10^{\frac{x}{6}}$$

step 4. ??????????????

Comment: Note that $0$ is a solution.

Comment: The other solution is about $13.6267$. These are the only two real solutions.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: are you sure? 0.1690366 and 45.92765242537 look close to solutions

Comment: there are three solutions according to my textbook and wolframalpha if you wanna paste the equation over there. I just dont know How to get to the solutions

Comment: @Henry: Could you have used the natural logarithm instead of the logarithm base 10? @Matt: Should you actually use the natural logarithm instead of logarithm base 10? ;p

Comment: I did overlook a solution though, about $0.4161$.

Comment: @ Raskolnikov, the problem came as base 10 in the text. How are you finding the solution?? I am still hung up on this step: (x^2)-(10^(x/6))+1=0

Comment: I used a pocket calculator. As already explained by Yuval and PEV, you should use some approximation scheme. PEV suggested Newton's method, I suggest iteration based on the form of the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $$x^2+1 = 10^{x/6}$$ or $$x^2-10^{x/6} +1 = 0$$ So one can use [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) (i.e. choose the initial point to be $x = 0$).

Comment: I.e. there's no analytic solution, although you can find an approximate solution using various methods. Newton's method is a numerical method for finding approximate solutions.

Comment: How would I solve for x after subtracting the 10^(x/6)?

Answer (score 1):

To find the biggest root, you can also iterate the equation as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=6\log(x_n^2+1)$$

Start for instance with $x_0=1$.

To find the other root besides the trivial $0$, you can iterate the following equation using the same seed as before:

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{10^{x_n/6}-1}$$

Finally, you could show by an analysis of the function $6\log(x^2+1)-x$ that these are the only three possible solutions.

EDIT: Extra reference on [fixed point iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_iteration).

Answer (score 0):

$$6\ln(x^2+1)-x=0$$
$$6\ln(e^t)-\sqrt{e^t-1}=0$$
for real $t$:
$$6t-\sqrt{e^t-1}=0$$
$$e^t=1+36t^2$$
$$\frac{1}{1+36t^2}e^t=1$$

It can be proved that your equation cannot be solved in terms of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) and [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Moreover, it can be proved that the equation doesn't have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

The equation can be solved in terms of Generalized Lambert W.